# Finding this key exist in object or not without loop in js

Tags: javascript

I have object `a` and object `b` .I want to check key of `b` exist in `a` or not without using loop how can I do this.

```
var a = {name1: "hello", game1: "no games", name2: "world"}
var b = {name1:'hello world'}
```

Yes I can do this using loop. First I can get all the keys of b in array and i can take each key at a time and find by using `.hasOwnProperty()` but I am looking for the method without using loop how is it possible.

Comment: `Object.keys(b)[0] in a`, but if `b` has more than one key then you will need a loop, no way around that.

Comment: if b is multiple objects then you need to use map Object.keys(b).map(t=>a.hasOwnProperty(t))

Comment: Why the restriction on a loop? All map/reduce/filter are loops too

Comment: Please update your question to detail if you want to check more than one key from B - people are confused

Comment: If you don't want loops, use recursion. But what have you gained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var a = {name1: "hello", game1: "no games", name2: "world"};
var b =  {name1:'hello world'};

var exists = Object.keys(a).includes(Object.keys(b)[0])
console.log(exists);
```

In case there are multiple keys in b to ckeck in a, it should be:

```js
var a = {name1: "hello", game1: "no games", name2: "world"};
var b =  {name1:'hello world', game1: "no games"};

var exists = Object.keys(b).every(bKey => Object.keys(a).includes(bKey));
console.log(exists);
```

Or just:

```js
var a = {name1: "hello", game1: "no games", name2: "world"};
var b =  {name1:'hello world', game1: "no games"};

var exists = Object.keys(b).every(bKey => bKey in a);
console.log(exists);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the keys are not known in advance (and there can be more than one key to check), you can use this trick:

```js
    var a = {name1: "hello", game1: "no games", name2: "world"}
    var b =  {name1:'hello world'}
    
    // Extract keys from a
    var keysA = Object.keys(a);

    // For each key from b, check if a includes it
    // See [1] if needed for every()
    console.log(
      Object.keys(b).every(function(k) { return keysA.includes(k); })
    );
```

Admittedly, this is very similar to using a loop.

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Answer (score 1):

```
You can also try underscore.js function _.findKey(object, predicate=_.identity])

Example:-
var users = {
  'barney':  { 'age': 36, 'active': true },
  'fred':    { 'age': 40, 'active': false },
  'pebbles': { 'age': 1,  'active': true }
};

_.findKey(users, function(o) { return o.age < 40; });

Output => 'barney' (iteration order is not guaranteed)
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is:

```js
console.log('game1' in {name1: "hello", game1: "no games", name2: "world"})
```

Comment: @AniketSahrawat: You're making the assumption that the key name is known in advance. If that was the case, then what's the significance of it being an object property?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP doesn't want to check a _single_ key, but _all_ keys in `b`.

Comment: Question was: "..I want to check key of b exist in a or not..". Not all keys in b

Comment: _first I can get all the keys of b in array and i can take each key at a time and find_